# Why doesn't Reader DC send a printjob to a shared printer in a terminal server environment?

Tags: printing, terminal-server, shared-printers, adobe-reader

I'm experiencing a very odd issue.

We work in a terminal environment using Adobe Acrobat Reader DC and printers that are shared on a print server and pushed to users in the Terminal Servers using a GPO.

Sometimes a user experiences an issue where Adobe Acrobat Reader DC will not send a printjob to a printer. The user presses print, but nothing happens. No printing pop-up, and no job gets sent to the printer queue.

When they re-add the printer, or print on a different printer, the issue does not occur.
Also, relogging resolves the issue.

Restarting the print spooler service, or killing all adobe reader tasks does NOT  resolve the issue.

I've experienced this with Ricoh and HP printers, and since the issue is not constant I do not get the feeling it's a print-driver issue.

Has anyone experienced this? Help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the latest drivers for systems ?

Comment: Hi @udoyen I am pretty sure we do. Are there any specific drivers you are referring to?

Comment: It appears only _Ricoh and HP_ printers have this issue ?

Comment: I've only experienced it with HP and Ricoh printers thus far, and only for specific users. Not sure if it is limited to those 2 types of printers though.

Comment: If other users are not having this problem then it's best to start at their systems.

Comment: udoyen, all employees work on 3 load-balanced terminal servers. The issue is not restricted to 1 of the 3 servers.